# MongoDb get only value but not key using php

Tags: php, json, mongodb, key

i am using mongodb and my query returns only a key value 
the following is the format of the `var_dump`

```
 <pre>array (size=471)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '162230' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '165333' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '181312' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '181313' (length=6)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '181314' (length=6)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '181315' (length=6)
  6 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '181316' (length=6)
  7 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '181317' (length=6)
  8 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '181318' (length=6)
  9 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '181319' (length=6)
  10 => 
    array (size=1)
      'sno' => string '181320' (length=6)</pre>
```

I do not want key . all i want is a array of values without a loop.

Comment: Consider trying with `implode();`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

```
 array_column($arr,"sno")
```

Comment: Good to note this is PHP doing this not MongoDB which your question would suggest is the wrong approach